# Copying files containing text, and files within several specifically named subfolders

Tags: linux

I have several folders like so:

- Folder A

  - 123-fanart.jpg
  - extrafanart

    - abc.jpg
    - def.jpg
- Folder B

  - 456-fanart.jpg
  - extrafanart

    - ghi.jpg
    - jkl.jpg

I'm looking to grab all jpg files containing "fanart" as well as all jpg contents of each extrafanart folder, and copy these all to a single folder like so:

- fanart

  - 123-fanart.jpg
  - 456-fanart.jpg
  - abc.jpg
  - def.jpg
  - ghi.jpg
  - jkl.jpg

I've gotten this far:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -iname "*fanart*" \) -exec cp '{}' fanart \;
```

But I can't figure out an efficient way to grab the contents of the extrafanart folders. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-o` to specify different criteria. You can use the `-path` option to match files in a subdirectory

```
find . -type f \( -name '*fanart.jpg'* -o -path '*/extrafanart/*.jpg' \) -exec cp {} fanart \;
```